# How to create config files

Tags: vps

Im trying to create a config file in UBuntu 15.10 VPS by doing this:

```
sudo nano $HOME/.yourcoin/yourcoin.conf
```

But when I try to exit and save it says error writing no such file or directory. I also tried `mkdir` but can't do it. I want to create this config file.

Comment: Why would you make such a file with `sudo`?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, you are trying to create a root access file (because you are using sudo), inside a hidden directory under $HOME. Also, the directory may not exist yet, so first try:

```
cd ~/.yourcoin
```

If it fails, it is likely that the directory does not exist, so then try:

```
mkdir ~/.yourcoin
```

Once you are sure the directory is there, then try:

```
sudo nano ~/.yourcoin/yourcoin.conf
```